# UITextField with autolayout constraints stops resizing if there's text

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UITextField with some autolayout constraints set up (image below). Whenever I add text initially it resizes normally. But after I stop typing and resign the textfield then try to type again it stops resizing.

Also I noticed that when I add text programmatically it also stops adhering to autolayout.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the Height constraint and adding a Bottom one?

Comment: Yeah changing the height doesn't help it results in basically the same issue.